# Bundle Install could not find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, spree-paypal-express

I run $ bundle install and the following message appears. I had to say rubygems(dot)org instead of the link because of the no more than 2 links rule for people under 10 rep.

> Updating git://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap.git
>   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.^Csungmoon@new-host-2:~/rails_project/cart$ >bundle install
>   Updating git://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap.git
>   Fetching gem metadata from rubygems(dot)org/.......
>   Fetching gem metadata from rubygems(dot)org/..
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Could not find gem 'spree_boostrap (>= 0) ruby' in >git://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap.git (at master).
>   Source does not contain any versions of 'spree_boostrap (>= 0) ruby'

My gemfile looks like this.

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>   gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
>
> gem 'sqlite3'
>   gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree'
>   gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise'
>   gem 'spree_core'
>   gem 'spree_backend'
>
> gem 'spree_paypal_express', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express.git'
>   gem 'spree_boostrap', :git => 'git://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap.git'
>
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
>   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
>   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "spree_boostrap" it's "spree_bootstrap" (you're missing a "t")

https://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

You most probably copy pasted the install code in the github page.  If you look closely, it's missing a t.  It should be

```
gem 'spree_bootstrap', :git => 'git://github.com/legiar/spree_bootstrap.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line in `Gemfile` to install the `spree bootstrap` gem

```
gem 'spree_bootstrap', github: 'jdutil/spree_bootstrap'
```